# Stackdriver alerting on pods with CrashLookbackOff

Tags: monitoring

I am trying to trigger alerts from Stackdriver for pods with the status 'CrashLoopBackOff'. So far, I've been able to trigger only alerts on cpu, memory but can't find this option.

The GKE cluster is running with Stackdriver Logging and Monitoring - Enabled v2(beta).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.